# Why my specific .htaccess for laravel and angular doesn't work?

Tags: .htaccess

my htaccess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"
RewriteEngine on

# Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png|tff)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

it causes and error "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"_______________________________________________

Comment: Could you please do let us know if you have any other rules too apart from these mentioned ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

into this

```
SetEnvIf X-HTTPS 1 HTTPS
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-HTTPS} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I dont know what is he doing but it works